# Compiled C ODE gives different results to R's using deSolve

Tags: r, c, desolve

I have an ODE which I would like to solve using compiled C code called from R's deSolve package. The ODE in question is I an exponential decay model (y'=-d* exp(g* time)*y):
But running the compiled code from within R gives different results to R's native deSolve. It's as is there they are flipped 180º. What's going on?

## C code implementation

```
/* file testODE.c */
#include <R.h>
static double parms[4];
#define C parms[0] /* left here on purpose */
#define d parms[1]
#define g parms[2]

/* initializer  */
void initmod(void (* odeparms)(int *, double *))
{
  int N=3;
  odeparms(&N, parms);
}

/* Derivatives and 1 output variable */
void derivs (int *neq, double t, double *y, double *ydot,
             double *yout, int *ip)
{
  // if (ip[0] <1) error("nout should be at least 1");
  ydot[0] = -d*exp(-g*t)*y[0];
}
/* END file testODEod.c */
```

## R implementation - Native deSolve

```
  testODE <- function(time_space, initial_contamination, parameters){
  with(
    as.list(c(initial_contamination, parameters)),{
      dContamination <- -d*exp(-g*time_space)*Contamination
      return(list(dContamination))
    }
  )
}

parameters <- c(C = -8/3, d = -10, g =  28)
Y=c(y=1200)
times <- seq(0, 6, by = 0.01)
initial_contamination=c(Contamination=1200) 
out <- ode(initial_contamination, times, testODE, parameters, method = "radau",atol = 1e-4, rtol = 1e-4)

plot(out)
```

## R implementation - Run compiled code from deSolve

```
library(deSolve)
library(scatterplot3d)
dyn.load("Code/testODE.so")

Y <-c(y1=initial_contamination) ;
out <- ode(Y, times, func = "derivs", parms = parameters,
           dllname = "testODE", initfunc = "initmod")


plot(out)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compiled code **does not give** different results to **deSolve** models implemented in **R**, except potential rounding errors within the limits of `atol`and `rtol`.

The reasons of the differences in the original post where two **errors** in the code. One can correct it as follows:

1. Declare `static double` as  `parms[3];` instead of `parms[4]`
2. Time `t` in derivs is a pointer, i.e. `*t`

so that the code reads as:

```c
/* file testODE.c */
#include <R.h>
#include <math.h>

static double parms[3];
#define C parms[0] /* left here on purpose */
#define d parms[1]
#define g parms[2]

/* initializer  */
void initmod(void (* odeparms)(int *, double *)) {
  int N=3;
  odeparms(&N, parms);
}

/* Derivatives and 1 output variable */
void derivs (int *neq, double *t, double *y, double *ydot,
             double *yout, int *ip) {
  ydot[0] = -d * exp(-g * *t) * y[0];
}
```

Here the comparison between the two simulations, somewhat adapted and generalized:

```r
library(deSolve)

testODE <- function(t, y, parameters){
  with(
    as.list(c(y, parameters)),{
      dContamination <- -d * exp(-g * t) * contamination
      return(list(dContamination))
    }
  )
}

system("R CMD SHLIB testODE.c")
dyn.load("testODE.dll")

parameters <- c(c = -8/3, d = -10, g =  28)
Y          <- c(contamination = 1200)
times      <- seq(0, 6, by = 0.01)

out1 <- ode(Y, times, testODE,
            parms = parameters, method = "radau", atol = 1e-4, rtol = 1e-4)
out2 <- ode(Y, times, func = "derivs", dllname = "testODE", initfunc = "initmod",
            parms = parameters, method = "radau", atol = 1e-4, rtol = 1e-4)

plot(out1, out2)          # no visible difference
summary(out1 - out2)      # differences should be (close to) zero

dyn.unload("testODE.dll") # always unload before editing .c file !!
```

[image: comparison between R and C code]

Note: set`.dll` or `.so` according to your OS, or detect it with `.Platform$dynlib.ext`.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed,I'd like to offer you some bounty on this when it becomes available! That has solved it. Why do I need to include a *t instead of just t? It says t is a pointer but surely it's a double as well, no?

Comment: It is a pointer to a double, i.e. the memory address of a double. Pointers can be very powerful, but also cumbesome, one of the reasons why we use R. Honestly, it is also possible to write models for deSolve in Fortran. More about pointers can be found in C programming books and for the impatient also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#C_pointers).